# Finding n-dimensional neighbors

Tags: python, arrays, recursion, dimension

I am trying to get the neighbors of a cell in an n-dimensional space, something like [8-connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_connectivity#8-connected) or 26-connected cells, but at any dimensionality provided an n-tuple.

Neighbors that are directly adjacent are easy enough, just +1/-1 in any dimension. The part I am having difficulty with are the diagonals, where I can have any quantity of coordinates differing by 1.

I wrote a function that recurs for each sub-dimension, and generates all +/- combinations:

```
def point_neighbors_recursive(point):
    neighbors = []
    # 1-dimension
    if len(point) == 1:
        neighbors.append([point[0] - 1])  # left
        neighbors.append([point[0]])  # current
        neighbors.append([point[0] + 1])  # right

        return neighbors

    # n-dimensional
    for sub_dimension in point_neighbors_recursion(point[1:]):
        neighbors.append([point[0] - 1] + sub_dimension)  # left
        neighbors.append([point[0]] + sub_dimension)  # center
        neighbors.append([point[0] + 1] + sub_dimension)  # right

    return neighbors
```

However this returns a lot of redundant neighbors.
Are there any better solutions?

Comment: Can you please show the output for a simple example, say 2D or 3D?  When I try your code in multiple dimensions, I get exactly the set of neighbouring points I expect: 3^dimension of them (including the original).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll bet that all you need is in the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html) package, especially the **product** method.  What you're looking for is the Cartesian product of your current location with each coordinate perturbed by 1 in each direction.  Thus, you'll have a list of triples derived from your current point:

```
diag_coord = [(x-1, x, x+1) for x in point]
```

Now, you take the product of all those triples, recombine each set, and you have your diagonals.

Is that what you needed?